# Sorting Integer Array (Using My Own Algorithm)- Java

Tags: java

I'm doing an extra credit assignment for my programming class. We're doing OOP and this example is to take an array and sort it. All the sorting code will go into the add method. I have some code already, and it works sort of.  As said in the title I have to create my own algorithm with my unique code. How do I go about sorting all the integers in a list from smallest to largest? (The integers being the values added with the add method.) Here's the instructions the instructor gave me:

• Walk down the array until you find the place where the new element should go. Since the list is already
sorted you can just keep looking at elements until you find one that is at least as big as the one to be
inserted.

• Move down every element that will go after the new element, that is, everything from the one you stop
on to the end. This creates a slot in which you can put the new element. Be careful about the order in
which you move them or you'll overwrite your data!

Now you can insert the new element in the location you originally stopped on. All of this will go into your add method.

The two classes of the program:

```
   private int[] list;
   private int numElements = 0;



   //-------------------------------------------------------------
   // Constructor -- creates an integer list of a given size.
   //-------------------------------------------------------------
   public IntList(int size)
   {
      list = new int[size];
   }
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Adds an integer to the list. If the list is full,
   // prints a message and does nothing.
   //------------------------------------------------------------

   public void add(int value)
   {
      if (numElements == list.length){
      System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
      }
      else
      { 
        list[numElements] = value;
        for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
            //May be I should use a nested loop?
            //for(k = 0; k <)
             if(value < list[i]){
                 list[i+1]= list[i];
                 list[i]=value;
             }
       }
        numElements++;

            }


      }



   //-------------------------------------------------------------
   // Returns a string containing the elements of the list with their
   // indices.
   //-------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      String returnString = "";
      for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++)
         returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n";
      return returnString;
   }
}
```

The other class:

```
public class IntListThing {


public static void main(String[] args){

          IntList myList = new IntList(10);
          myList.add(84);
          myList.add(27);
          myList.add(250);
          myList.add(18);
          myList.add(94);
          myList.add(8);
          myList.add(87);
          System.out.println(myList);
       }
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: So, "your own algorithm" is actually insert-sort?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the post for more clarification.

Comment: Your instructor's instructions look good enough for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you find the right place i.e. `if(value < list[i]){` is true **then move all available elements to right. You are moving only one by using `list[i+1]= list[i];`.**

i.e. use a small loop as:

```
  for(int j= numElements-1; j>=i; j--){
      list[j+1]= list[j];
  }
  list[i] = value;
```

Please note: This is the concept. Please adjust the index and conditions.

**EDIT: I missed to mention that you need to break as soon as the element is inserted.** Also I corrected the conditions. Here is the updated `else` block code.

```
        list[numElements] = value;
        for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
            //May be I should use a nested loop?
            //for(k = 0; k <)
             if(value < list[i]){
                 for(int j= numElements-1; j>=i; j--){
                      list[j+1]= list[j];
                  }
                  list[i] = value;
                  break;
            }
        }
        numElements++;
```

Comment: How do I go about moving all of them? Should I use a nested loop?

Comment: @recheej `System.arraycopy` (suggested by `Perception`) seems like a good idea

Comment: @Jan Dvork I can't use any outside methods.

Comment: @recheej what don't you understand of this code? Have you even tested it?

Comment: @recheej: Sorry I wasn't here. The above loop is indeed a nested loop and goes inside your `if(value < list[i]){` block.

Comment: @recheej: As I mentioned, you need to correct the conditions. Give me a minute, I will update the answer with exact loop and conditions.

Comment: @recheej: Sorry I missed to mention that you need to break the `for` loop when you find the right position for your value. I updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Bravo. Thank you very much. I was sitting there for a long time trying to figure it out. You helped out a lot. You did not bash me and I actually learned from your answer.

Comment: @recheej Good to know that I was helpful and your learnt. we are here to help only.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to make an impact with your prof, then do a binary search for the insertion spot. Once you find it, exit that loop and enter another, where you copy everything beyond the insertion spot one place to the right.

### Edit

As @Jan Dvorak sharply points out below, even the binary search is a waste of CPU time and programming effort :)

Comment: Impressive but inefficient ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Which part? Not the search, I suppose. Doubling array size and keeping track of last legal index is even more complication, I don't dare suggest that. Now I see, it's a fixed-size list.

Comment: "copy everything up" on each iteration sounds quadratic. Not that insertion sort is not worst-case quadratic by itself... ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Forget it, I was assuming OP is already doing it, so I didn't want to enter even more complication. This is actally a fixed-size list.

Comment: This will work ;-) Note that the swapping can be combined with the linear search, so I'm not sure the binary search is a speedup.

Comment: @JanDvorak There's no copying to the left of insertion point, so the faster you skip to it, the better.

Comment: If you linear-search from the right, you can swap and search in the same pass.

Comment: @JanDvorak True, that would be the best approach here. Come on, write an answer :)

Comment: Note that linear-search insertion sort seems optimal for mostly sorted arrays ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework assignment many will be reluctant to giving you direct code.

What you hinted at in your comments, using a nested loop, is necessary. Your goal with this loop is to "push back" every element in `list` by one spot. Some considerations:

1) Be sure to check the bounds of your array. If your array is "full" then pushing things over the limit will result in `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

2) Be careful not to overwrite any values as you move through the loop. May I suggest starting at the back and moving forward?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class IntListThing  {
private int[] list;
private int numElements;

public IntListThing  ( int initial_capacity ) {
    list = new int[initial_capacity>0?initial_capacity:1];
    numElements = 0;
}

public void add(int value)  {
      if (numElements == list.length) list = Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length*2);
      int i = 0;
      for ( i = 0 ; i < numElements ; ++i ) 
          if ( value < list[i] ) break; 
      for ( int k = numElements ; k > i ; --k )
          list[k] = list[k-1];
      list[i] = value;
      ++numElements;
}

public String toString()  {
      String returnString = "";
      for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++)
         returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n";
      return returnString;
   }


}
```

This way you also don't have to worry about your array getting full, it gets resized when it needs to.

In the Arrays class you can find all sorts of other useful methods. You should definitely check it out. You have the binarySearch that someone suggested using, but that would be very inappropriate here since in this method you already have linear complexity for copying the array so whats the point in doing the search in logarithmic time.

I hope you get that extra credit.

If you want to practice some more try making a remove method that also resizes the array when needed to conserve space. Let me know in the comments if you need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The classic insertion sort works by swapping an element to the left until it's sorted, then moving on to the next element, only writing the element being moved to the place where it isn't overwritten:

```
- input: array a
- for i from 1 to a.length-1: // the first element is already sorted!
  - temp = a[i];
  - j = i;
  - while (j>0 && a[j-1] < temp):
    - a[j] = a[j-1];
    - j = j-1;
  - endwhile
  - a[j] = temp;
- endfor
- output: a
```